# How to recover datas from a class of service in a custom plugin?

Tags: migrations, plugins

So to be a little clearer, I'm creating a source migrate plugin that extends SourcePluginBase and not SqlBase. I get my data from a class of service, but I would like to know how to bind them to the fields () and prepareRow() methods in the documentation example? Since I do not have the query () method.

Any help?

Comment: What example are you referring to?

Comment: Do you know the module Migrate Plus which provides SourcePluginExtension - an abstract source plugin class providing a standard mechanism for specifying a source's IDs and fields via configuration and also examples how to use it?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the link @leymannx https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-a-sql-source

Comment: Yes i know but i 've created a custom plugin class that extends SoucePluginBase @4k4

Comment: The class i've mentioned does the same. Either use it directly or if you don't like the module then at least use it as example.

Comment: ok i will try it!